# Unable to mine Ether on testnet

Tags: mining, mist, testnets

My blockchain is in sync and I'm mining using the Mist wallet on the **testnet**, but I have been mining for three days and have not yet mined any Ether. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you follow a particular set of instructions when doing this?

Comment: If you give your address I can send you some ether.

Comment: If you managed to solve your challenge, please post an answer, so others can benefit from what you learned.